# Dashboard / Reports not reflecting updated state of the object

Tags: lightning, reporting, dashboard

Say we have a custom object `My_Object__c` and we have a report and dashboard that just lists all objects in the org.

Suppose we only have one record in this object.

If we open our dashboard / report, it shows us the record.
Then, we change the field values of the record (e.g. `Count__c` change from `0` to `1`) and try to refresh dashboard or re-run the report. The data in the report, however, does not update.

If we go to the record page and refresh that a couple of times, then go back to the report, the data is updated.

This suggests that reports/dashboards are using SLDS or some other form of caching in the browser. Is there a way to cache bust this somehow in automatic or semi-automatic fashion so users don't have to refresh records individually?

Answer (score 0):

Dashboards are refreshed asynchronously, and make take significant time. Note that the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dashboards_refresh.htm&type=5) says:

> When dashboard data is being refreshed, the Refresh button changes to Refreshing...You can leave the dashboard and do other things in Salesforce while the data refreshes. When the dashboard has finished refreshing, Salesforce 1 tells you that the dashboard is ready through the right-hand notification panel. Since push notifications aren’t enabled for dashboard refreshes, you're notified only in the app and not in through email.

> TIP If your dashboard data doesn't refresh after ten minutes, the refresh automatically stops. If necessary, click Refresh again.

This means that it can take up to 10 minutes to even get a refresh, and if it expires, you have to request a refresh again. The amount of time taken depends on any other refreshes in your org as well as server load and number of records being tallied. Note that the report itself should show the correct data if you click through to it, but the dashboard will not until you're notified of the update.

Comment: well, this is the thing, the report does NOT show the correct data for us :(

Comment: @zaitsman Are you talking about the chart data? The same rule applies. Only by directly running the report can you get realtime data (Reports > Click on Report Name).

Comment: Nope, according to my team if we click on the report name and we see the data, then we change our Object through API via our in-house connected app, and then refresh that report (e.g. refresh browser or edit and run report) the data in the report does not reflect updated object fields

Comment: ...until such time that they open the actual object record in the browser (that always shows the right fields) and then go back to the report